# C# Reading and writing **ONE** binary file

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

I have a pair of binary files that will be updated in place.

If I create a BinaryReader and a BinaryWriter for both files as soon as they are opened and then use them everything's fine.

However, three of the four objects are actually only used by one method, they shouldn't exist outside those methods--but if implement it in the proper way the attempt to create the first writer fails because it's not writable.  It most certainly is writable, I didn't touch the open code.

Is there something about closing the BinaryReader that affects the underlying filestream object??

Comment: Yes, You must dispose or close that object, or else, next time when you re-try to open or write something, it will throw an error, can you post your code?

Comment: Could you post any code?